# Json to Object using Gson

Tags: java, json, enums, gson

I have a class **DocumentBO** which has the following attributes -

```
public class DocumentBO implements IStorageBO {
   private String aId;
   private String studyId;
   private Map<AlgorithmsEnum, JobIOStatus> status;
   private String text;
   private Collection<Sentence> sentences;

   public String getaId() {
      return aId;
   }
   public void setaId(String aId) {
      this.aId = aId;
   }
   public String getStudyId() {
      return studyId;
   }
   public void setStudyId(String studyId) {
      this.studyId = studyId;
   }
   public Map<AlgorithmsEnum, JobIOStatus> getStatus() {
      return status;
   }
   public void setStatus(Map<AlgorithmsEnum, JobIOStatus> status) {
      this.status = status;
   }
   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
   public void setText(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }
   public Collection<Sentence> getSentences() {
      return sentences;
   }
   public void setSentences(Collection<Sentence> sentences) {
      this.sentences = sentences;
   } 
}
```

The **AlgorithmsEnum** is as follows -

```
public enum AlgorithmsEnum {
   SENTIMENT("sentiment"),
   INTENTION("intention"),
   TOPIC("topic"),
   NER("ner"),
   UIMA("uima");

   private final String value;

   private AlgorithmsEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String value() {
      return value;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return value;
   }

   public static AlgorithmsEnum fromValue(String value) {
      if (value != null) {
         for (AlgorithmsEnum aEnum : AlgorithmsEnum.values()) {
            if (aEnum.value().equals(value)) {
               return aEnum;
            }
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

The **JobIOStatus** is also similar.
I am successfully able to create a JSON string of Collection using GSON using the following TypeToken

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<DocumentBO>>() {}.getType();
```

But, when I try to recreate the Collection object using the JSON string returned by Gson and the same `TypeToken`, the key of the `status` hashmap is always returned as **NULL** whereas the value is successfully created. What do you think can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have overridden `toString()` in your `enum`.

If you look at the JSON being produced, the keys to your `Map<AlgorithmsEnum, JobIOStatus>` are the lowercase names you're creating. That won't work. Gson has no idea how to recreate the `enum` from those when you attempt to deserialize the JSON.

If you remove your `toString()` method it will work just fine.

Alternatively you can use the `.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()` method in `GsonBuilder` when serializing which will ignore your `toString()` method and produce JSON using the default representations of your `enum` values which is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

There are "well" known :) issues of Gson to serialize Map when the key is derived from object and its not a "native" data type.
Please use this

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();    
Gson gson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create(); 
Collection<DocumentBO> obj = gson.fromJson(str, type);
```